# Getting "Unexpected reserved word" using Node 0.12.7 on Linux

Tags: linux, node.js, class, syntax-error

I’m using node 0.12.7 on the following version of Linux …

```
[davea@mydevbox Automate-04-01-2016]$ uname -a
Linux mydevbox.evo-text.com 2.2.8-35.46.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 16 17:15:34 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

However when I try and run my file I get this error

```
[davea@mydevbox Automate-04-01-2016]$ node start.js 
Validation Complete
/home/davea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:25
const builder = require('./builder');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/davea/Automate-04-01-2016/js/Optimus.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Following some random advice online, I added “—harmony,” but I still get this error …

```
[davea@mydevbox Automate-04-01-2016]$ node --harmony start.js 
Validation Complete
/home/davea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:97
class Builder {
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/davea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:25:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

How do I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade to a newer version of node (e.g. v4.x or newer).

You can find ES6/ES2015 compatibility for various node versions [here](http://node.green/).